# How to convert PCollection<TableRow> to PCollection<Row> in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have one `PCollection` of `TableRow`. I want to use `SQLTransformation` over that `PCollection`. I tried to use `SQLTransformation` directly over `PCollection<TableRow>` but it is giving the below error:

**Code Snippet**

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = [...]
PCollection<Row> rows1 =   rows.apply(SqlTransform.query("SELECT max(ID) as max_watermark FROM PCOLLECTION"));
```

**Error**

```
[main] WARN org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO - Unable to infer a schema for type com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow. Attempting to infer a coder without a schema.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getSchema when there is no schema
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getSchema(PCollection.java:331)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.schema.BeamPCollectionTable.<init>(BeamPCollectionTable.java:35)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.toTableMap(SqlTransform.java:183)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:138)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand(SqlTransform.java:110)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:548)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:360)
        at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:162)
```

As per the document, **SQLTransformation** requires `PCollection<Row>` as an Input so I tried to convert `PCollection<TableRow>` to `PCollection<Row>` with the below logic but that is giving an error with respect to Coder.

**Logic I tried**

```
final Schema schema = Schema.builder()
    .addStringField("ID")
    .build();

PCollection<Row> rows11 =  rows.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, Row>() {
    @ProcessElement
    public void ProcessElement(@Element TableRow inRow, OutputReceiver<Row> out){
            Row r = Row.withSchema(schema)
                    .addValues(inRow.get("ID"))
                    .build();
            out.output(r);          
    } 
}));

PCollection<Row> rows12 =   rows11.apply(SqlTransform.query("SELECT max(ID) as max_watermark FROM PCOLLECTION"));
```

But this is giving the below error. I don't know what I am missing here.
*my complete use case is to get a max of the id column value from **rows** (`PCollection<TableRow>`) and store it in one of the BigQuery table.*

**Error**

```
[main] WARN org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO - Unable to infer a schema for type com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow. Attempting to infer a coder without a schema.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for ParDo(Anonymous)/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).output [PCollection@185939155]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
  Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide a coder for a Beam Row. Please provide a schema instead using PCollection.setRowSchema.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.Preconditions.checkStateNotNull(Preconditions.java:471)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.getCoder(PCollection.java:284)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.finishSpecifying(PCollection.java:115)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.finishSpecifyingInput(TransformHierarchy.java:154)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:547)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:482)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:360)
        at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:159)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `.setCoder(RowCoder.of(schema))` on the resulting `PCollection<Row>`. They are also defined at PCollection level.

Please check https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas for more information.

Comment: Did the solution above resolve your issue?